# Remove elements from one array whose Indexes are present in another aray

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm

an array A1 containing N objects.another array A2 containing numbers that represent indexes into the first array. You need to remove elements from A1 for which indexes are there in A2 and produce the compacted array. For example:

```
A1 = [ a, b, c, d, e, f, g ] // N elements and N is large
A2 = [ 5, 1 ] // k elements and k is small (and constant)
Answer = [ a, c, d, e, g, _, _ ]
```

I wrote the C# code like :

```
public class CompactingArray
{
    private Compact(array A1 , array A2)
    {
        var hash = new Hashset<int>(A2);
        foreach(int c in hash)
        {
            A1.remove(c,1);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(A1);
    }
}
```

I need O(n) complexity code and not to use any inbuilt functions. Please suggest a C# code without using any built-in functions.

Comment: no, it was asked in an interview and i presented answer using inbuilt function remove but they require no inbuilt function and linear complexity .

Comment: If we answer, do we get the job?

Answer (score 5):

If `k`, the number of elements in `A2`, is "small and constant", then a trivial algorithm of O(N*k) complexity (for each element in `A1` see if its index is in `A2`) would be considered linear:

```
int writingPosition = 0;
for (int i = 0 ; i != N ; i++) {
    boolean found = false;
    // Since k is constant, this loop is considered constant-time
    for (int j = 0 ; j != k ; j++) {
        if (A2[j] == i) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        A1[writingPosition++] = A1[i];
    }
}
while (writingPosition != N) {
    A1[writingPosition++] = "_";
}
```

However, it would not be optimal. For an improved performance, you could sort `A2` (sorting it is a constant-time operation). Once `A2` is sorted, you can make an `int current=0`, an index into `A2`, then walk the `A1` array from zero to `N`, and skip over indexes from `A2[current]`. At each iteration of the loop to `N` you need to look at only one element of ``A2`, so overall the algorithm is linear, too.

The implementation would be similar to the above, but instead of using the nested loop and checking `if (!found)` you would check if `A2[current] == i`, and adjust `current` accordingly.

Comment: Yes, if `A2` was always sorted the complexity would be `O(n)` with only one loop. See my answer that I wrote before reading your description under the code ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Here is solution.

```
        Char[] A1 = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g' };
        int[] A2 = { 5, 1 };

        int k = A2.Length;

        int N = A1.Length;

        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        {
            A1[A2[i]] = '\0'; // place null charcater here
        }

        Char[] copy = new char[N];

        for (int i = 0,j=0; i < N; i++) // place all values in sorted order
        {
            if (A1[i] != '\0')
                copy[j++] = A1[i];
        }
        for (int i = (N-k); i < N;i++ )
        {
            copy[i] = '-';
        }
        Console.WriteLine(copy);
```

Comment: The result is missing the two last `_`.

Answer (score 0):

Is the order of the resulting array important? If not, you could do something around the lines of:

```
char[] a = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g' };
int[] z = { 5, 1 };

int zlen = z.Length;
int amax = a.Length - 1;

for (int i = 0; i < zlen; i++)
    a[z[i]] = a[amax - i];
```

Finally, you would have to resize the resulting array (`a` itself) to chop `zlen` elements off from the end of the array. This solution just bubbles the elements to be removed to the end of the array. No sequential removal required. Add in the duly checks for index bounds etc.

Comment: This doesn't work either. It produces `{ 'a', 'g', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'g', 'g' }`

Comment: @t3chb0t: Clearly, you didn't read the text that surrounds the code you "tested".

Answer (score -2):

`O(n)` complexity is possible if `A2` is sorted because then you can do it with only a single loop where you index each array separattely:

```
var A1 = new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g" }; // N elements and N is large

var A2 = new int[] { 1, 5 }; // k elements and k is small (and constant)

A2 = A2.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();

var A3 = new string[A1.Length];

int m = 0; // To check it runs only n times.
int leftItemCount = A1.Length - A2.Length;
for (int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, l = leftItemCount; i < leftItemCount || m < items.Length; i++)
{
    m++;
    if (j < A2.Length && k == A2[j])
    {
        j++;
        k++;
        A3[l++] = "_";
        i--;
        continue;
    }
    A3[i] = A1[k];
    k++;
}

// Answer = [ a, c, d, e, g, _, _ ] for { 1, 5 }
// Answer = [ a, d, e, g, _, _, _ ] for { 1, 2, 5 }
```

---

Test code:

```
static void ArrayTests()
{
    // Item array lengths.
    for (int i = 45; i < 256; i++)
    {
        var items = Enumerable.Range(0, i).Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();

        // Number of tests per array.
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
        {
            // Items to remove.
            Random rnd = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
            var remove = new int[rnd.Next(1, i)];
            HashSet<int> indexes = new HashSet<int>();
            for (int k = 0; k < remove.Length; k++)
            {
                int index = 0;
                do
                {
                    index = rnd.Next(0, i);
                } while (indexes.Contains(index));
                indexes.Add(index);
                remove[k] = index;
            }
            remove = remove.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
            var result = ArrayTest(items, remove);
        }
    }
}

static string[] ArrayTest(string[] items, int[] remove)
{
    var A3 = new string[items.Length];

    int m = 0;
    int leftItemCount = items.Length - remove.Length;
    for (int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, l = leftItemCount; i < leftItemCount || m < items.Length; i++)
    {
        m++;
        if (j < remove.Length && k == remove[j])
        {
            j++;
            k++;
            A3[l++] = "_";
            i--;
            continue;
        }
        A3[i] = items[k];
        k++;
    }            
    Debug.Assert(m == items.Length);
    return A3;
}
```

Comment: k, is not constant, k can be for example = n or even worse k=n^2 or even worse (k=2^n) with no effort, so being formal, you can't ignore it as a constant. So, sorting an array with k items is not constant, if k is not large, most programming languages don't use Quicksort which is O(n^2) in the worst case, but it has a average case of O(nlogn) complexity, they use O(n^2) algorithms like Bubblesort, so your algorithm complexity also depends on k. I think it's not correct considering it constant.

Comment: I've tested it with different `k`s and the loop always runs with `O(n)` and produced correct results so far. I know that this is true  if `k` is sorted which I wrote above the code.

Comment: With no intention to argue, my friend. Have you tested using k=O(n^2) items or even k=O(2^n)? One single loop can be exponential, even producing correct results.

Comment: I've added test code. It runs no more then `O(n)` times for no matter how long array. There's an `m <` condition but it only makes sure the last item gets replaced if the last item was removed.